# Which data sets would help to predict (exponential) market trends?

Tags: dataset, clustering, predictive-modeling

Which kind of datasets do websites such as [MeetGlimpse](https://meetglimpse.com/), [trends.co](https://trends.co/), [explodingtopics.com](https://explodingtopics.com/) use to detect exponential market trends? I love them (not affiliated) and would like to better understand how they work.

I would assume they somehow buy access to clickstream data or something similar? Any hints?
Also, which algorithms/approaches do they use?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look, my guess would be that maybe they mine data from some predefined target websites, typically social media: twitter, facebook, etc. I could imagine that they capture trends in the sense of "what people are talking about" on social media platforms, but maybe they have other sources and methods.

There are Natural Language Processing methods which can be used: the basis would be some form of topic modelling, then there could be some more specific applications such as event detection. We can't know how much manual post-processing is involved though, there could be a manual filtering to remove irrelevant stuff.